# How to simulate visual push for image button in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, button, web, controls

I'm developing an asp.net web application and I have some image button controls, how can I simulate the visual clicking of it? I don't mean triggering the event, just visually seeing that the button is pushed like normal buttons do, thanks

Comment: Here's one way: http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css tags.  See this livedemo: http://img.usabilitypost.com/0812/active_button/index.html

Instructions here:  http://www.usabilitypost.com/2008/12/16/pressed-button-state-with-css/

Edit:  The code for ease's sake.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Button Test</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body {
            padding: 40px;
        }
        #button {
            display: block;
            width: 135px;
            height: 43px;
            background: url(button.png) no-repeat top;
        }
        #button:active {
            background: url(button.png) no-repeat bottom;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a id="button"></a>
</body>
```

Also, if you're extremely new to CSS and don't really want to reinvent the wheel you could use a base css interface like Twitter's Bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons